# No signature of method: build_8holhrjpptrvtx84vjg1strvw.android() (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

`No signature of method: build_8holhrjpptrvtx84vjg1strvw.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_8holhrjpptrvtx84vjg1strvw$_run_closure1) values: [build_8holhrjpptrvtx84vjg1strvw$_run_closure1@48f15b44]`

Comment: please add your code that caused the error.

Comment: the code is in here => https://pastebin.com/CtQ6Arj1